# Two title pictures with TikZ Poster? Positioning on the upper right and left site?

Tags: align, posters, tikzposter

I want to use 2 logos, 1 in the left, 1 in the right corner near the title. I'm not able to get two of them aligned properly. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=18mm, colspace=18mm, subcolspace=0mm]{tikzposter}
    \usetheme{Desert}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Für weitere Autoren im Titelbereich
\usepackage{authblk}


    \title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text} 
    \author{AdamG} 

    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image-b}}


\author[1,2]{It is my name}
\author[1,2]{perhaps yours}

\affil[1]{first Institute}
\affil[2]{second Institute}




\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \@title \par} %\textsc
        \vspace*{4em}
        {\LARGE \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[scale=0.8,anchor=east,xshift=0.51\linewidth,yshift=6cm,inner sep=0pt] {%
       \@titlegraphic
    };
}
\makeatother


    \begin{document}

      \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Used `\hfill` you will get it

```
 \documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Desert}

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text} 
\author{AdamG} 
\institute{Graduate Center}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image-b}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer, but this is not working for me. There is no difference between using \hfill or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you have adjusted to a different part of other question I am using an adaptation of that one.
[image]

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=18mm, colspace=18mm, subcolspace=0mm]{tikzposter}
    \usetheme{Desert}

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text}
\author{KJO is my name, Perhaps Yours Goes here.}% If you need two lines it should be possible to add \\ between them
\institute{First Institute, Second Institute.}% If you need two lines it should be possible to add \\ between them

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.19\linewidth}%
\includegraphics{example-image-a}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited my post because I did a mistake. I forgot some important details in the example. In my  case, your answer pushes one of the logos out of the viewable part of the pdf. Can you help me again?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It fits now. When you have a longer list of authors and institute, what can I do to get this same looking then? I would use \usepackage{authblk}

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to modify it.